# Errors when creating vnext Test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Using VS2015 Preview I've tried to create a test project (vnext library(dll)). using the example from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/18/asp-net-vnext-in-visual-studio-14-ctp-3.aspx)

```
//Test Class
    using System;
    using Xunit;
    namespace testproject.Tests
    {

        public class Class1
        {
            [Fact]
            public void TrueisTrue()
            {
                Assert.True(true);
            }
            [Fact]
            public void OnePlusOneIsTwo()
            {
                Assert.Equal(2, 1 + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

//project.json

```
        {
        "version": "1.0.0-*",
        "dependencies": {
            "Xunit.KRunner": "1.0.0-beta1"
        },
        "commands": {
            "test": "Xunit.KRunner"
        },
        "frameworks": {
            "aspnet50": {
                "dependencies": {
                    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231"
                }
            },
            "aspnetcore50": {
                "dependencies": {
                    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231"
                }
            },
            "k10": {
                "dependencies": {
                    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231"
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm getting these errors in the error window, but the tests do run correctly. Is this a bug in the beta, or am i missing something in my configuration?

[image: Error List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `k10` section is deprecated and should not be in `project.json`
- `aspnet50` doesn't need `System.Runtime`